# Newbie Django filter uniques 2 many values

Tags: django, forms, filter, unpack

i am trying to filter the uniques from a list with this form:

```
class SpecForm(ModelForm):
    a = Doctors_list.objects.values_list('specialty', flat=True)
    unique = {z: i for i, z in a}
    qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique.values())
    specialty = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=qs)

class Meta:
    model = Doctors_list
```

everything seems correct for me, but i get this error: `too many values to unpack`

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct statement should be this:

```
unique = {z: i for i in a}
```

Are you specifically trying to put those values into a dictionary? This will yield a list:

```
unique = [ i for i in a ]
```

If you go with this, you will have to remove the `.values()` in `qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique.values())` leaving it like this:

```
qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique)
```

What's going on here is that with brackets in the first approach you're creating a dictionary with just one key and a list as a the value of that key. When you issue `.values()` you get a list with the dictionary's values. So it's pointless to use a dictionary.

With the second approach you get a list directly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am trying to make a select menu, i need the list filtered

Comment: Well, I think you should better go with my second approach and then remove the `.value()` in `qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique.values())` leaving it like this: qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique)

Comment: i get a problem here now: qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique.values()) ---->'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: See the comment above, I'll edit my answer. Remove the .value() in qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique.values()) leaving it like this: qs = Doctors_list.objects.filter(id__in=unique)

Comment: I did what you told, but i get a strange error with the first item on the list: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Dentista'`

Comment: I see, do `Doctor` has an specialty field? You are trying to get doctors that filtering unique specialties am I right? See the problem there is that `id` is numerical and the `unique` list is a list of strings.

Comment: you are rigth, so i can use this method to filter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29321/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-claudioa)